# Is it possible to draw horizontal and vertical line with Bresenham's line drawing algorithm?

Tags: 2d-graphics, line-drawing, pixel-graphics

In computer graphics Bresenham's line drawing algorithm used to draw line . But i want to know the properties why i can't draw vertical and horizontal line by this algorithm.

Comment: If you are smart you dont ise it!

Comment: The algorithm works in the eight octants. Drawing a line from (0,0) to (let's say) (10,0) should quite straightforward. Start with that and it'll be easy to see why it doesn't step as expected.